# Detect object in image and change background of image

Tags: java, android, image-processing

To implement an android project in which camera takes photo .

i want to change the background of the image .

what steps need to be done to detect the object in the image and crop the object to apply different background

OR

Simply change the background .

Is it require image processing .Is their any library for image processing available.

Thanks

Comment: 1. Find all borders, 2. Find object, 3. Fill everything outside object by new background. What kind is the object? BTW, if background is not monochrome and/or object have colors like background, it would be too hard to find this object.

Answer (score 2):

The best library for image processing with android (only arm support yet) is [JavaCV](https://code.google.com/p/javacv/), it's a Java interface for [OpenCV](http://opencv.org/) which is the standard library for image processing in C++.

[Here is an example](https://code.google.com/p/javacv/source/browse/samples/FacePreview.java) of face detection in Android, with all the configuration hints for your AndroidManifest.xml.

EDIT : [here is an example](https://code.google.com/p/javacv/source/browse/samples/MotionDetector.java) using contour detection.

Answer (score 2):

You need to find an approach to determine what pixels are background and what are not.

The complexity will depend on the visual characteristics of your background. If it is a fixed color (like television chroma key) it will be very simple. Just replace pixels of such color. If it is a landscape, it will be more complicated.

I suggest starting from the simplest approach and them improve your solution.

You can also work with a fixed camera and two photographs. Take the first photo (only the background) and another one with the objects in the scene. Find the difference between two images you know what is background and what is object.

[Here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D5mBt0kRYvk) (at 00:50) is shown an example of chroma key application performed in real time. The background is collected (photo without objects in the scene) before the processing.